# How to insert static A record freely like in Mikrotik DNS?

Tags: active-directory, dns-zone

How can I create static A record freely like in Mikrotik DNS? for example: my primary zone is example.local and I want to create google.com, mail.google.com and so on records with desired Ip address like 192.168.10.50 and forward any other records to the main name server and ask from (google.com).
If I create google.com zone and insert A record inside, any not exist records makes error not-existent domain in nslookup command.
In mikrotik you can do it easily by adding static record and its ip address.